# Trying to convert 1 condition to 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I currently have the following formula in A3:

=iferror(if(A1="","",1),0)

I want to change it so that this logic remains the same but A2 should also be checked to make sure it is False. If A2 is false, the same logic of the formula above should apply when it is false.

If A2 is true, it should behave the same way as the logic above, when it is true.

I'm having trouble properly converting this :-/

I was trying it with =AND but got confused how to make sure that the same logic applies as the check above when A2 is False and True respectively.

Comment: Made some edits after I got my logic confused in the description above. Should be correct now.

Comment: Try show your sample data and expected output, i don't think you need `iferror` here.

Answer (score 0):

Iferror only checks if the entire expression returns an error, not a cell by cell. To get what you want, you should modify your condition to simply check for an error in cell a1 `or` a2, and then write your if statement based on that. Assuming you want a `0` if either cell has an error, then this should work: `=if(Or(ISERROR(A1),ISERROR(A2)),0,if(A1="","",1))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IF((A1="")*(A2=FALSE),, 1), 0)
```

which reads as: if A1 is empty and A2 equals false output empty cell otherwise output 1 and if any kind of error occurs output 0